# Monitoring pacemaker with url trigger external agent

Tags: debian, high-availability, pacemaker, alerts, corosync

I have a HA setup, which now the only resource configured is Heartbeat with Active/Passive Configuration. Both running Debian 7, 64-bit in the cloud.

Now i want to trigger an URL with the information from the Pacemaker when the resource changes. 
The URL is pointed to some server which will send E-mail/an SMSalert ect.. Let the URL triggered be http://example.com/pacemaker.php?CRM_notify_node=node1&CRM_notify_rsc=blah

Since Configuring all the stuff in Pacemaker is lil tedious. So all the processing or sending E-mail/alerts is put into the webpage.

So, how to configure the Pacemaker to call the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can configuring [Notifications via External-Agent](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-notification-external.html) adding external script to process  cluster changes.

For example configure ClusterMon to execute an external-agent:

```bsh
primitive ClusterMon ocf:pacemaker:ClusterMon \
    params user="root" update="30" extra_options="-E /path/to/pcmk_curl_helper.sh" \
    op monitor on-fail="restart" interval="10"

clone ClusterMon-clone ClusterMon \
    meta target-role="Started"
```

Script `pcmk_curl_helper.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Generates alerts for any failing monitor operation or
# for any operations (even successful) that are not a monitor
# env vars: ${CRM_notify_recipient} ${CRM_notify_rsc} ${CRM_notify_rsc} ${CRM_notify_desc} ${CRM_notify_status} ${CRM_notify_rc} ${CRM_notify_target_rc}

if [[ ${CRM_notify_rc} != 0 && ${CRM_notify_task} == "monitor" ]] || [[ ${CRM_notify_task} != "monitor" ]] ; then

    /usr/bin/curl -sS http://example.com/pacemaker.php?CRM_notify_node=${CRM_notify_node}&CRM_notify_rsc=${CRM_notify_rsc} > /dev/null

fi
exit 0
```

Alternatively you can start [crm_mon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/crm_mon) as a background daemon and use same script to process cluster changes.

Eg.

```
crm_mon -d -i 30 -p /tmp/ClusterMon_ResourceMonitor.pid -E /path/to/pcmk_curl_helper.sh
```

I hope this help.