# crm_mon -E does not run the external-agent on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, high-availability, pacemaker, reporting, corosync

## Setup

I'm currently having a working 2-nodes HA cluster using Pacemaker+Corosync. My nodes are running on Debian 8 (Jessie). Now I would be able to get notified when changes occur in the cluster (resources stop/start, promote/demote, move...).

Since email reporting is so-2008, I'd like to use Slack.
To do that, I created a script that uses `curl` to post a message to my team's Slack channel, using Slack's [webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks). My script is using environment variables that are documented here: [Pacemaker - 7.3. Configuring Notifications via External-Agent](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/s-notification-external.html).

The script works fine when executing manually in the shell and is able to post on the specified channel. It also logs to `/var/log/ocf-notifier.log`.

## Problem

Based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/653094/335285), I created a new resource in the cluster using Pacemaker's `ocf:pacemaker:ClusterMon` resource agent, which calls my custom script (`/usr/local/bin/ocf-notifier`).

However I noticed that my script is simply not called at all when changes occur in the node (tried stopping resource as well as completely shutting down a node).

Therefore, I tried to launch `crm_mon` by hand like the following:

```
$ crm_mon -Arf --interval=2 -E /usr/local/bin/ocf-notifier -e '@jordan'
```

And see if this could trigger the thing by playing around with the cluster with another shell. As it turns out, `crm_mon` was able to see the changes happening in the cluster (node going offline, resource being stopped/started...), but my custom script never blinked an eye. My custom log file remains empty, and nothing appears in Slack since I believe the script is simply not called.

## TL;DR

`crm_mon` does not call the external agent on cluster events, as it should with `-E` option.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your script, omitting sensitive parts if needed?

Comment: Here's a pastebin to the script: http://pastebin.com/RGuY9htQ. The thing is, the script is working fine if launched manually. It is just not called by `crm_mon`...

Comment: Two more questions: 1.) Which software versions are you using? How did you install / build these? 2.) Could you show your configured `ClusterMon` resource?

Comment: 1) `crm` 2.1.3, `Pacemaker` 1.1.12, `corosync` 2.3.4, they have been installed using `apt-get install pacemaker`. 2) `cluster_mon_p` primary resource: http://pastebin.com/3pCsMdSP

Comment: From which repo did you install `pacemaker`?

Comment: `deb https://ppa.mmogp.com/apt/debian jessie main`

Comment: Turns out the repo `ppa.mmogp.com` is down for some reason today. I initially installed this repo when I was following the instructions [over here](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian-HA/ClustersFromScratch) on how to setup a HA cluster.

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I did not try again in the end because I needed to focus on other things, and my setup is now pretty stable and fail-safe. Despite not being actively looking for a solution, any new clues are more than welcome!